# Dual boot windows 10 with ubuntu already installed

Tags: boot, windows

Here's my situation. I already have **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** installed and now I want to add windows 10 as second boot. There all the tutorials available to remove Ubuntu and install windows or install linux as dual boot when windows is already installed. I want to add windows 10 as dual boot where I have Ubuntu already installed.

Comment: You need to create a partition for Windows (using e.g. gparted) format it to ntfs and then boot windows and install it on the new partition.

Comment: Huge difference if UEFI or BIOS install? Windows only installs in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives and only in BIOS boot mode to MBR(msdos) partitioned drives. And Windows BIOS version typically erases Linux extended partitions on major updates, so an install may erase partition table if MBR. Be sure to have good backups whether UEFI or BIOS. With UEFI Windows wants multiple partitions, so let it create partitions it wants. If BIOS, it must be a primary NTFS partition with boot flag.